# cpputest error message allocation/deallocation

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cpputest

I am receiving this error message when using cppunit to test my application

```
Allocation/deallocation type mismatch
allocated at file: <unknown> line: 0 size: 262144 type: new []
deallocated at file: <unknown> line: 0 type: delete
```

I have already solved this particular problem, my question is how do I enable better information instead of unknown file and line 0?

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbols?

Comment: I have compiled everything with -g (using clang), according to the man page, that sounds like the flag I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include "MemoryLeakDetectorFreeMacros.h" and/or "MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h" in every sourcefile in your code under test, and also define CPPUTEST_USE_MEM_LEAK_DETECTION.

Most compilers have a flag you can use to automatically include a header in every source file; gcc has -include and MSVC has /FI.